# Storage using HDInsight hadoop

Tags: .net, azure, hadoop, bigdata, azure-hdinsight

I am pretty much curious to know one information about hadoop hdinsight.

This article from microsoft : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-hadoop-use-blob-storage/

explains that hadoop internally uses storage account for storing the data.

Assuming the above information to be the approach , then whats the difference between hadoop and storage account.
If I want to just store the information like files etc I can just make use of storage account only instead of creating hdinsight hadoop?
Also if hadoop '**hadoopCluster**' uses storage account '**stgAccount**' does that mean that storage account '**stgAccount**' space and '**hadoopCluster**' space are same ?

Answer (score 1):

Basically in a HDInsight deployment, you have two parts:

1. The HDInsight cluster which is made of multiple head and worker nodes (virtual machines where the software is running)
2. The Azure Blob Storage where you store data.

The Azure Blob Storage is a safe distributed storage for you data. You can use it whether you use HDInsight or not. This is just a cloud storage with its own pricing. So if yo just want to store files in the cloud, you definitely do not need HDInsight.

The HDInsight Cluster is not. Actually, you will see that whatever you store for example on the disks of the Head node directly will disappear once in a while.

The HDInsight Cluster has access to the storage you've specified when creating the cluster and can read/write data to this storage.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to benohead's response, you can either use [Azure Blob store](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-introduction/) as the storage or the newly released [Azure Data Lake Store](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/data-lake-store/) (ADLS) - which is a highly scalable and performant store for Big Data workloads. Since HDInsight separates compute from storage it is possible to use the VMs for compute and either Azure Blog or ADLS for storage. You can use Azure Blob or ADLS without using the compute provided by HDInsight.